# footer div no being consistant in position

Tags: css

all three footers have the same html and css code but actiing differently in each of the three pages. some times its at bottom, at other page its in the middle, at the other its at bottom but making a gap between its previous div (#main)

```
jsfiddle.net/BBnzW/ 
jsfiddle.net/6cYQg/ 
jsfiddle.net/USSds/
```

any guess why?
Please only answer after making sure in jsfiddle that it works. I have done alot of tries before.

The code is above stackoverflow code limit of 30000chars, so cant paste here.

Comment: what different actions from 3 pages you are getting?please elaborate..

Comment: Instead of including (or trying to) 30,000 lines of code, created a simplified example using the **minimum** amount of code to reproduce the problem. This will help us help you.

Comment: @sourcecode seee updated question

Comment: @bookcasey the situation do not allow partial code.

Comment: i think your footer is at absolute position ,you need to give it auto position depending on your content... can you share your css for the footer?

Comment: the css is in the fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#main { position: absolute }` is causing the footer to position in the middle of your content. And `.w1 { padding-bottom: ... }` and `#footer { margin-top: ... }` are producing the extra white space. But I don't think removing that will completely solve your problem.

Seems like you are trying to get a sticky footer. Try this http://jsfiddle.net/fL4XF/18/. Simple css and no extra markup. It works in IE7.

Here's another [Sticky Footer](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/using-sticky-footer-code.html) that works in IE6. However, it needs extra markup. It's up to you.

Comment: Nice !I have to use main as absolute to make its internal divs position correctly... are there work arounds? and if you answer, it seems I had a valid question. (still someone down voted me)

Comment: How do you need to position your internal divs? If you are using floats you can set `overflow: hidden` to the parent element so it will fit its children's dimensions.